# "Seaweed is nutritious. Children can eat "it" more often." - can the "it" be omitted?

Tags: meaning

**Example 1**

> "Seaweed is nutritious. Children can eat it more often."

**Example 2**

> "Seaweed is nutritious. Children can eat more often."

Do the examples mean the same thing?

Why can we omit the "it" in Example 2?

Comment: *Can* is a strange word to use here, because it's simply about ability.  I think you might mean they *should* eat it more often.

Comment: @stangdon The "it" should be included?

Comment: Yes, just like oerkelens said.

Comment: I agree with @stangdon that I would say "Seaweed is nutritious. Children *should* eat it more often." I would use *can* to talk about what a child is permitted to eat. So I might say "Children can eat ice cream each week." *Should* is better here because we are recommending that the children do something specific, not only permitting it.

Answer (score 7):

If you do not include *it* in your second sentence, there is no link between the two sentences, and the meaning of the second sentence certainly changes.

*It* in your second sentence refers to *seaweed*, so compare

> Children can eat seaweed more often

with

> Children can eat more often

Obviously, the second sentence just refers to eating in general, so it implies children can have more meals per day. That is not the same as children eating more seaweed.